# Bring GoogleMaps InfoWindow to front

Tags: google-maps, infowindow

I have a GoogleMaps APIv3 application in which multiple InfoWindows can be open at any one time. I would like to be able to bring an obscured InfoWindow to the front of all other InfoWindows if any part of it is clicked - similar to the behaviour of windows in MS Windows OS.

I had thought to add an onclick event handler which increases the z-index of the InfoWindow, but the event handler does not appear to be firing. 
ZIndex is a global variable that keeps increasing as InfoWindows are clicked - or thats the theory anyway.

Can anyone help ?
Here is my code:-

```
var ZIndex=1;
var iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content:contentString });
google.maps.event.addListener(iw, 'click', handleInfoWindowClick(iw) );

function handleInfoWindowClick(infoWindow) {
   return function() {
      infoWindow.setZIndex(ZIndex++);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

there is no click-event for an infoWindow, it's a little bit more difficult.

1. you'll need to use an element(not a string) as content for the infowindow, because you need a DOMListener instead a listener for the infowindow-object
2. when domready-fires, you must apply the click-DOMListener to the anchestor of this content-node that defines the infowindow

The following code will do this for you, add this to your page:

```
google.maps.InfoWindowZ=function(opts){
          var GM = google.maps,
              GE = GM.event,
              iw = new GM.InfoWindow(),
              ce;

             if(!GM.InfoWindowZZ){
                GM.InfoWindowZZ=Number(GM.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX);
             }

             GE.addListener(iw,'content_changed',function(){
               if(typeof this.getContent()=='string'){
                  var n=document.createElement('div');
                      n.innerHTML=this.getContent();
                      this.setContent(n);
                      return;
               }
               GE.addListener(this,'domready',
                               function(){
                                var _this=this;
                                _this.setZIndex(++GM.InfoWindowZZ);
                                if(ce){
                                  GM.event.removeListener(ce);
                                }
                                ce=GE.addDomListener(this.getContent().parentNode
                                                  .parentNode.parentNode,'click',
                                                  function(){
                                                  _this.setZIndex(++GM.InfoWindowZZ);
                                });
                              })
             });

             if(opts)iw.setOptions(opts);
             return iw;
        }
```

Instead of `google.maps.InfoWindow()` you must call now `google.maps.InfoWindowZ()`

It also returns a genuine InfoWindow, but with the mentioned listener applied to it. It also creates the node from the content when needed.

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/tRwnE/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/tRwnE/)

---

Updated version for visualRefresh(using mouseover instead of click) [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/uuLBb/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/uuLBb/)

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks that does exactly what I needed.
However, is there a small bug on the line of code :-

if (ce){
    GM.event.removeListener(cc);    //this should be ce ?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it should be ce,  fixed it in code above and in the fiddle.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying this solution but I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'InfoWindowZ' of undefined`.

Comment: You must load the maps-API before the function

Comment: this is old af but really helped me. Thanks !