# How to bring in front an openWindow?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have multiple markers moving on the map in real-time. Each one have an opened openWindow.

When two markers are at proximity, I cannot edit data in the openWindow because the openWindow of the other marker overlaps the first one.
As there is no mousemove event for the infoWindow, how could I bring in front an openWindow ?
I have no code to be proposed ...

**EDIT:**
The question is different of this one: [Bring GoogleMaps InfoWindow to front](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348092/bring-googlemaps-infowindow-to-front): click on the marker brings the openWindow in front.

If I click on the marker, another type of infoWindow is displayed. Therefore, no click on the marker for me !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bring GoogleMaps InfoWindow to front](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348092/bring-googlemaps-infowindow-to-front)

Comment: I modified my question ...

Comment: Your question is not different. The other question is older, the markup of the infoWindows has been changed with the visualRefresh. Updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/uuLBb/

Comment: You are right. I must study this solution. Thank you !

Comment: Could you comment the visual refresh flag. Why did you set it to false ? Soon the default value will be true. Shall I change it later ?

Comment: don't care about the flag, it's a leftover. The used API-version in the fiddle is 3.exp(currently 3.14)...this flag doesn't have any effect in this version. You may remove it.